# Cannot assign value of type ''[UIImage]'? to type 'UIImage' (swif3)

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview, uiimage, blend-mode

I am trying to save 2 uiimages together then put the combined image and have it equal a image view named finalImage. However I am getting the error message that I have assign the title my question. Just looking to put the combined uiimage in a image view.

```
  @IBOutlet var finalImage: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let bottomImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "pic")!
    let topImage:UIImage = UIImage(named:"wall")!
    // Change here the new image size if you want
    let newSize = CGSize(width: bottomImage.size.width, height: bottomImage.size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, bottomImage.scale)
    bottomImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: newSize.width,height: newSize.height))
    topImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: newSize.width,height: newSize.height), blendMode:CGBlendMode.normal, alpha:1.0)
    let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
 //error line
   finalImage.image = newImage.images

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried doing finalImage.image = newImage? 
You're trying to assign an array, to single image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73389241/ive-tried-everything-cannot-assign-value-of-type-uiimage-to-type-uiimag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your newImage is UIImage, so put

```
finalImage.image = newImage
```

because, you have `UIImage` type, not `[UIImage]` - array of UIImage objects, in `finalImage.image`