# I've tried Everything -> Cannot assign value of type '[UIImage]' to type 'UIImage'

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I have this line of code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   
    @IBOutlet var GoToSettings: UITabBarItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var dogFact1: UIImageView!
    
    var onlyImageView = 1

    @IBAction func nextFactGo(_ sender: Any) {
        
        
        print("NextFactRequested")
        
        dogFact1.image = [ //uploadedimage, //uploadedimage, //uploadedimage] [Int.random(in: 0...3)]
        onlyImageView += onlyImageView + 1
        //image is second in view
    }
    
    
    }
weak var tavbarvar: UITabBar!
```

**Note i've changed the actual image into `//uploadedimage` to make code snippet shorter**

I attain an error at: `dogFact1.image = [etc...]`

I tried this previously and it worked...

I'd be really grateful if you could edit the code so that it would work + an explanation would be out of this world!

Comment: ```dogFact1.image =  uploadedimage ```

Comment: May be the space between «]» and «[Int.random…»

Comment: What is the type of uploadedImage : UIImage or [UiiMage] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error it self explains what the issue is.

`Cannot assign value of type '[UIImage]' to type 'UIImage'` means your variable is expecting a value of type `UIImage`. But u are assigning a value of type`[UIImage]`(an array of UIImage).

So instead of `dogFact1.image = [ //uploadedimage, //uploadedimage, //uploadedimage]` use  `dogFact1.image = uploadedimage`.